# How to find sum of elements of diagonals in 2d ArrayList?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, multidimensional-array, sum

I don't know how to access elements in 2D `ArrayList`. I need to find the sum of diagonals in 2D `ArrayList`.

`List<List<Integer>> arr`

Comment: `value = list.get(i).get(i);`

Comment: Thank you, sir!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {

        int size = arr.size();
        int add1=0;
        int add2=0;
        for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++){
           add1 = add1+  arr.get(i).get(i);
           add2 = add2+ arr.get(i).get(size -i-1);

        }

        int absoluteValue =Math.abs( add1 - add2);

        return absoluteValue;

    }
```

Comment: Although your answer explains well to the question how to access the elements of the 2D arraylist. The function result basically returns the difference of the sums of the leading and anti-diagonal elements. You should add some explanation to the code as best practice.

Comment: @Debi I will make sure I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see you used **diagonals** in your question. A matrix has two diagonals, the **leading diagonal** (`\`) and the **antidiagonal** (`/`).

Assume your matrix, the 2d array, or 2d arrayList whatever you called, is a `i * i` matrix, you can calculate in a loop:

```
int leadingDiagonalSum = 0, antiDiagonalSum = 0;
int size = arr.size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    leadingDiagonalSum += arr.get(i).get(i);
    antiDiagonalSum += arr.get(i).get(size - i - 1);
}
```

The above codes are easy to understand. If you really want the **sum of diagonals**, you can add the two variables.

**However, you should check the `size`, if it is an odd number, you should subtract the central element once after the sum.**

Answer (score -1):

```
    int diagnolSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        diagnolSum += arr.get(i).get(i);
    }
```

Comment: explain your answer